# Call function in C with less parameters

Tags: c, parameters, parameter-passing

By Mistake I called a function with less parameters that what it has in its prototype , the code compiled with no warnings, so i did the following experiment:

compiled and ran the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
   printf("1 param  %d \n",f(1));
   printf("2 params %d \n",f(2,7));
   printf("3 params %d \n",f(7,8,9));
}

int f(int a, int b)
{
  return (a+b);
}
```

I compiled it using `gcc try.c`
it compiled without warnings
and the results were

```
1 param  -557760119 
2 params 9 
3 params 15
```

my question is how come the compiler compiled with no issues, even when i called f() function that gets two parameters either with one or three parameters
Thanks,

Comment: I am a little surprised that compiled at all, much less without warnings, considering that you did not even place a prototype for the function before its first use.

Comment: legacy.  Long ago, someone thought it would be a good idea to allow implicit function declarations.  Turn up the diagnostics on the compiler.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium , the question is a question about principal, if i put a prototype with two parameters before the main() , it would fail on "too few argument" or "too many argument", i was just surprised that without the function declaration it compiled, gave no warning and ran

Comment: A permanent employee where I was hired on a temp contract also suppressed compiler warnings because she didn't think they were important... You can imagine the code... _"The compiler helps those who help themselves."_

Comment: In what version of GCC does that compile with no warnings?

Comment: An empty parameter list in a function prototype means "any number and type of parameters". So, `int f();` as a prototype would fit all 3 calls.

In this case the compiler needs `-O2 -Wall` to catch the uninitialized variable `b` in `f` when only 1 parameter is given.

https://godbolt.org/z/cz5dY8a46

Comment: By the time you call `f()` inside `main()` there is no prototype in scope. You can swap the definitions of the functions (`f()` before `main()`) because a definition also serves as a prototype ... or add the prototype all on its own: `int f(int, int);`

Comment: @EricPostpischil , originally i tried on an old machine with `GCC 4.7` , then i tried also on newer one with `GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019 (uses GCC 9.2)`

Comment: @RuudHelderman , thanks, I searched and missed this answer , this really gives an comprehensive answer

Answer (score 3):

C language is now a rather old language. In the first versions (known as K&R C or pre-ansi C from the 70's) functions prototypes did not exists, and the declaration of a function only declared the return type. As the default return type was `int` some programmers (many?) used not to declare functions returning `int` values. And this legacy behaviour is still observed by current compilers: if the compiler sees a function usage with no previous declaration, it assumes that it is a function returning `int` and taking an arbitrary number of parameters.

So the compiler is right when it compiles your code with no errors.

That being said, calling a function whose *definition* expects a precise number of parameters with a different number of parameter or with wrong parameter types invokes Undefined Behaviour. That means that *per standard* no requirement exists on how the program will behave at run time. Said differently **never do that in a real world program**.

For the actual results, many compilers use the so-called C calling convention: the parameters are put in the stack in reverse order by the caller, the callee uses them using the current position of the stack pointer, and in the end, the stack is cleared by the caller. This is the reason why passing more parameters than expected is thinked to be harmless. Anyway it still explicitely invokes UB, so a different compilation (different compiler or compilation options) could lead to a very different behaviour. And it also explains why passing less parameters than expected just let initialized values (the current content of the stack) for the missing parameters.

But what you should remember is only that passing a wrong number of parameters or using wrong parameter types is explicitely Undefined Behaviour, even if the absence of a definition can prevent the compiler to raise an error.